# Read Parquet files with Pandas from S3 bucket directory with Proxy

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, parquet, python-s3fs

I would like to read a S3 directory with multiple parquet files with same schema.
The implemented code works outside the proxy, but the main problem is when enabling the proxy, I'm facing the following issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 158, in <module>
    df = pq.read_table(source=bucket_path, filesystem=s3).to_pandas()
  File "pyarrow\parquet\__init__.py", line 2737, in read_table
    dataset = _ParquetDatasetV2(
  File "\pyarrow\parquet\__init__.py", line 2351, in __init__
    self._dataset = ds.dataset(path_or_paths, filesystem=filesystem,
  File "pyarrow\dataset.py", line 694, in dataset
    return _filesystem_dataset(source, **kwargs)
  File "pyarrow\dataset.py", line 447, in _filesystem_dataset
    factory = FileSystemDatasetFactory(fs, paths_or_selector, format, options)
  File "pyarrow\_dataset.pyx", line 2031, in pyarrow._dataset.FileSystemDatasetFactory.__init__
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 144, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 100, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: GetFileInfo() yielded path 's3://test/files/part-00000-ed788628-0a6d-4ce9-b604-dd4c6ec75b6d-c000.snappy.parquet', which is outside base dir 's3://test/files/'
```

Here is the code. I commented the other solution I've tried:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import s3fs

bucket_path = 's3://test/files/'

os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://proxy.com:4200'
# proxies = {
#        'https': f''http://proxy.com:4200',
#        'http': f'http://proxy.com:4200'
#    }

# s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False, config_kwargs={'proxies': proxies})

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)

df = pq.read_table(source=bucket_path, filesystem=s3).to_pandas()
```

I couldn't find anyone with the same problem. Any help is welcomed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```py
bucket_path = 's3://test/files/'
```

with:

```
bucket_path = '/test/files/'
```

Since the path will be passed to the given filesystem instance inside of pyarrow, according to the document of `fsspec`, the path should come without a scheme.